# How would I align css height to size of browser window?

Tags: javascript, css, alignment

Ok, so I want to place a video so that it's height is 100% of the browser window, but not the video, so instead of the video height being 1080px (with scrollbars) but the height relative to how tall the browser window is. 
Here is my current styling (it works):

```
video {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 100%;
}
```

I'd like it to look like this:

[image]

--Meaning no padding and no scrollbar. I've tried the viewport height css property, but that causes a scrollbar. The code aforementioned does yield the results I am looking for, but it is an extremely inefficient way to do such a simple thing, and I do not know if it will display the same way in other browsers. Here it is [live](http://henrysprojects.x10host.com/never/gonna/give/you/up/)...
Is there a JavaScript alternative? Or better yet pure-css?

Comment: You Could define the aspect ratio with SASS.

Comment: Rick Astley is not the best example to use ;). Also why are you using 4:3 video?

Comment: I want the black borders on the sides but not on the top as shown in the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Alohci](https://stackoverflow.com/users/42585/alohci) explained that I should use `vertical-align: top;` to remove the scrollbar, with help from him and other answers from [Scott Marcus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/695364/scott-marcus) and [Timothy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3148260/timothy). All received answers were helpful and contributed to the final answer seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5wszaa9h/2/).
So, my **previous** css:

```
body {
  background-color: #000000;
}

video {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 100%;
}
```

And my **new** css:

```
body {
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

video {
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Percentage heights of elements in the normal flow of the document only work when an ancestor element has had its height definitively set.

But, to skip all of that, set it to 100% of the viewport height:

```
height:100vh;
```

Comment: I tested "video {text-align: center; height: 100vh;}" and, it still caused a scrollbar.

Comment: @Henry7720 - text-align needs to be on the containing block element (i.e. body), not the video element. To get rid of the scrollbar, use `video {vertical-align:top;}`

Comment: @Henry7720 Also, keep in mind that the default sizing in the box-model is that padding, borders and margins are not taken into account when setting the `height` or `width` of an element.

Answer (score 1):

Reset the Body and HTML Tag then you can use 100% and get true 100% height and width.

```css
 html, body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 

            }
#fullscreen-video{
  width:100%;
height:100%;
  background-color:green;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="fullscreen-video">
<iframe id="video" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/A3PDXmYoF5U" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Setting `width:100%` on `html, body` makes no difference because that is the default value and if `fullscreen-video` had more ancestor layers, every single one of those elements will have to have their `height` set if percentages are being used.